# AutoKey Ctrl+Meta bind not working in xterm

Tags: xterm, keymapping, autokey

This is my AutoKey script:

```
keyboard.send_keys("<up>")
```

It works perfectly in the default Ubuntu terminal and everywhere else.

But when I try to use it in xterm nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

See here for details: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/132

AutoKey does not work with xterm by default, because xterm ignores "synthetic" key presses.

You can enable AutoKey in xterm by holding [CTRL]+[Left Mouse Button] to show xterm’s main menu and checking the allow SendEvents option.